# Starting Mincha right before Shekiya

Tags: halacha, time, zemanim, mincha-afternoon-prayer

According to those who pray Mincha only up to Shekiya (sunset), are you required to finish Mincha before Shekiya or just required to begin it before Shekiya? (Sources.)

Comment: I've heard that you should at least get through kedusha by shekiya.

Comment: @Daniel: I have heard a few different ways, however I am looking for a source.

Comment: I think this has been asked here before. There is a famous aruch hashulchan who is mattir going late.

Comment: @DoubleAA: If it was asked before I will delete. I could not find this question here. If you have the Aruch HaShulchan please post as an answer.

Comment: see end of this answer http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22004/759

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer (which is used for so many other things as well) is from Bilaam. No wonder you ask it now this week.

The gemoro says in B'rochos 7a that Bilaam could work out the exact microsecond when G-d was angry. Tosfos asks what Bilaam could possibly say in that microsecond. One answer given is that he could say just one word: Destroy. Another answer given is that, once he started speaking his curse at the exact microsecond, he could continue speaking (and cursing) as long as he wanted.

So according to Tosfos's first answer you have to finish in time, but according to the second you don't.

The same as when G-d is angry, if you start 'on time' that means catch the second you can keep his anger 'going'. How much more so that when he is not angry and awaits our t'fillos to fulfill them that if one starts on time, hashem will have patience to wait until we finish.

Comment: Which Gemara, where? What do you mean "already"?

Comment: This is the simple answer? This is the complicated answer.

Comment: You'll note i already linked to this tosfot in the comments to the question. Can you show it has anything to do with zmanei tefillah? Those don't necessarily work like random moments of divine fury/ compassion.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Please don't edit your answers to make them go away. If you're sure your answer isn't valuable, delete it. If you think your answer is valuable, leave it around, even if someone else has already said approximately the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for adding the Daf citation. +1 (after edits).

Comment: @Daniel, I believe the non-answer was a form of protest/frustration with our questions and critiques. I've edited it to clarify parts that were unclear, and for formatting.

Comment: @Chanoch, better?

Answer (score 1):

[Aruch HaShulchan 110:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=193) says that if one began on time, even if he finished after the Zeman it is considered Tefila B'Zmana.

However I have heard that the Mishna Berura disagrees and says that one must finish the entire Tefila by the Zeman. (will put in source as soon as it is found)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Harav Haim Kanievsky Shalit"a writes like the Mishna Berura.