# If you start Shacharit Shemoneh Esrei during zman, and finish it out of zman, what is the halacha?

Tags: zemanim

If you start Shacharit Shemoneh Esrei during zman, and finish it out of zman, what is the halacha?
For example, if you are davening towards the end of the 4th halachic hour, and you start Shemoneh Esrei just before the end, but finish after the end of the 4th halachic hour, does it still count as the full mitzvah?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37665/finished-kriat-shema-after-the-deadline  The Aruch Hashulchan and the proof from Bilaam would apply in this case.

Comment: https://dinonline.org/2016/12/27/wont-finish-davening-until-after-zman-is-up/

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29462/759

Comment: Zman tefillat shacharait extends until hatzot hayom anyway....what's the question here?

Comment: @יהושעק Whatever line you want to hold of, the question holds for that line.

Comment: @יהושעק Ayin the machaber in siman פט, lemayseh it's bedieved to daven shacharait after daled sha'ois, ein hachi nami you get schar tefilah, but it's not the mitzvah.

Answer (score 1):

See the Aruch Hashulchan is siman פט who asks this point exactly. He brings a Tos' who deals with the question of how Bilaam could have cursed the Jews in the one split second during which God gets angry. In one of Tos' answers he says that if he started the curse during that moment and continued afterwards it would still count. The Aruch Hashulchan suggests that this should also apply here. But, it should be noted that other poskim are strcit on the point.

Comment: I am familiar with such a piece in  סימן ק"י אות ה   , but I can't find such a piece in סימן פ"ט. Can you please give the exact citation.

Comment: Lechoirah you're right about that. my apologies