# Correct procedure for davening in Synagogue after sof zman tefila

Tags: halacha, tefilla, synagogue, zemanim

In America, it is very common for shuls to start quite davening *shacharit* quite late on Shabbat.  Suppose someone is going to be attending a synagogue that will not reach *shmoneh esrei* before *sof zman tefila*. What would be the halachicly preferable course of action?

1) Daven with the minyan late

2) Daven *shmoneh esrei* at home before coming to shul and then again with the minyan (How would one do this?  Would he have to say all of *pesukei d'zimra* and *kriat shema* at home?)

3) Daven *shmoneh esrei* at home and then not join the minyan in it's silent recitation

4) Some other procedure

Comment: I believe (3) is the generally accepted halakha; those who hold by Chabad follow option (1).

Comment: @Tatpurusha, if you have a whole shul doing something (and it is not only Chabad shuls that daven late - New Square is 11am Shabbos morning start time, and there is one shul for the whole group) how can you define Yechidim who do otherwise as the "generally accepted halakha"?

Comment: @Yishai I asked a rav (in private) about this and he said that davening b'zman overrides davening b'tzibbur. If you hold by Chabad or another group that davens late, then of course the hilchos are different.

Comment: This chasidic practice is not to daven late like it is done today but to say the whole of t'hillim first etc. Just to come to shul late is not chassidus

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whether you follow the letter of the law as codified in Shulchan Aruch (89:1) and daven before the *zman tefillah*, or follow a Chasidic practice that is not particular about following the set times for *Shma* and *Tefillah*. This point of contention has been in existence since the beginnings of the Chasidic movement and here is just [one source for this practice](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3624&hilite=b4bcea4c-4bf0-41aa-acab-f8edf849760d&st=%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2&pgnum=128). (For a more thorough treatment see [here](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2008/09/chassidic-zemanim-davening-late.html).)

*Mishne Berurah* (46:32) writes that one should daven without a minyan rather than davening with the minyan after the *zman tefillah*. When joining the minyan later, one should answer Amen and recite Kedusah. etc., but should not daven again since he already davened. He should also stand when the *tzibbur* say *Shmone Esrai* (102:1)

However, common practice *lechatchila*  among many Chassidic groups is to daven with the minyan.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22003/halachic-justification-to-not-pray-the-amidah-before-zman-tfilah/22004#22004

Comment: @Yishai - very interesting!