# Shacharis after chatzos

Tags: halacha, zemanim, shacharis-morning-prayer, acharonim, chatzos

Is praying shacharis after chatzos (midday) permitted, and do you fulfill your obligation? If so, until when? Please give sources, preferably quoting the Mishna Berurah, Alter Rebbe of Lubavitch, or Rama.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22003/halachic-justification-to-not-pray-the-amidah-before-zman-tfilah

Comment: What if one starts davening just before chatzot but reaches chatzot while in the middle of shmoneh esrai? Does one continue to the finish or stop at chatzon (or 1/2 hour after, if relying on that view)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See orach chayim siman 89, first siff in Ramma that once it hits chatzos its assur to daven. Mishna berura brings different opinions that if it was by accident one has a half hour after chatzos to daven, but one should assume like Ramma that there is no half hour make up time and therefore wait the half hour till mincha time, daven mincha, then pray a tashlumin for shachris. This applies only to one who missed zman tfila by accident. If one skipped a tephila on purpose there is no way to fix that.

Comment: How do u do tashlumin, does that include yishtabach and birchos krias shema etc, and woudl it be permited to daven all of that first, then count the shmoneh esray as minchah>?

Answer (score 4):

Lechatchila person should not do it, if he already did in first half-hour after chatzos it is ok bedieved, but if already chatzos passee an one did not pray, he should do tashlumin after praying mincha.

[mishna berurah 89:1:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%98#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90)

Comment: What kind of tashlumin, what about the song of the sea, birchos yishtabach, krias shemna, uva litzion,,,>?

Comment: Yistabach you can't see anymore, once you davened, shmone esre, cause it was established to be said before.

Shema you can say whenever you want, obviously without berachot before and after,

Uva LeTzion you can say whenever you want as as well, since we saying it on TIsha b'Av by Mincha.