# What kind of Shacharis Tashlumin

Tags: tefilla, tashlumin

I'm aware of this question [Halachic justification to not pray the amidah before zman t'filah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22003/halachic-justification-to-not-pray-the-amidah-before-zman-tfilah) which says that according to some, you don't need to do tashlumin for shacharis after chatzos since it's time is all day, but assuming like the other opinions who say you do, what kind of tashlumin is required?

I heard some people say that one should daven everything like normal, except at shemoneh esrei have in mind that it's actually mincha, and then daven another shmoneh esrei after (don't know how MUCH after, maybe it can be after aleinu??), but I don't know the basis for this.

Can anyone give a source for the above practice, or otherwise one for what else one must do when making up shacharis? 'Cause there's not only shmoneh esrei to worry about, but what about saying ashrei three times a day, song of the sea every day, boruch she-amar...

Answer (score 2):

The idea of Tashlumin comes from [Gemoro Brochos 26a {Gemoro Hebrew text, Sefaria English elaboration}](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.26a.11-21?lang=bi)

> ….......... אמר רבי יוחנן טעה ולא התפלל ערבית מתפלל בשחרית שתים שחרית
> מתפלל במנחה שתים

> Rabbi Yoḥanan said: One who erred and did not recite
> the evening prayer, prays in the morning prayer two Amida prayers; one
> who erred and did not recite the morning prayer, prays in the
> afternoon prayer two Amida prayers.

1. Tashlumin is only for the shemoneh esrei. See [O Ch 108 (1) MB [3]](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.108.1?lang=bi&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=en) who says:

> ולענין ק"ש אם יש לה תשלומין עיין לעיל סוף סימן נ"ח ובמה שכ' שם במ"ב ועי"ש עוד דברכת ק"ש אין לה תשלומין לכו"ע דהיינו אפילו אם ירצה לברך אותם בעת שקורא ק"ש פעם אחרת עם ברכותיה דלא תקנו חז"ל תשלומין אלא לתפלה שהיא בקשת הרחמים

> As far as Shema if it has Tashlumin see above... and see there that the brochos of Shema do not have Tashlumin according to all opinions, that is even if one wants to say them when reading Shema another time (= after the time) with its blessings, for Chazal did not
> institute Tashlumin except for “tefilloh” (=  shemoneh esrei) which
> is requests for mercy.

2. Regarding the  Tashlumin for the Shacharis  shemoneh esrei  [O Ch 108 (1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.108.1?lang=bi) the mechaber states:

> If one erred or was forced [by circumstance] and did not pray the
> morning prayer, one prays the afternoon prayer twice: the first is the
> afternoon prayer, and the second as compensation.

3. As far as when to say the Tefillas Tashlumin, Mishna Berurah says [O Ch 108 (2) MB [11]](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.108.2?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.108.11&lang2=bi)

> כי תפילת השלמה צריכה להיות בעוד שעוסק בתפילה החיובית

> that it should
> be at the same time when one is occupied with the prayer that is
> obligatory at that time.

[Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tashlumin#cite_ref-7) summarises from Shulchan Oruch O Ch 108,

> In general, one shouldn't make any interruption in between the
> original Shemonah Esrei and the Tashlumin besides for certain prayers
> which are mentioned in the following halachot:
>
> If one needs to say Tashlumin for Arvit one should say Shacharit
> Shemona Esrei, Tachanun, and Ashrei and then the Tashlumin Shemona
> Esrei.
>
> If one needs to say Tashlumin for Shacharit one should say Mincha
> Shemona Esrei say Ashrei and then say the Tashlumin Shemona Esreh.
>
> If one needs to say Tashlumin for Shacharit one should wear tefillin
> for mincha, both for the mincha shemona esrei as well as the tashlumin
> shemona esrei.
>
> If one needs to say Tashlumin for Mincha, according to some poskim,
> one should say Arvit Shemona Esreh and Ashrei and then the Tashlumin,
> while others say that one should just say Avrit Shemona Esreh and then
> Tashlumin after waiting the time it takes to walk 4 amot.

This shows that it is possible to have an “Ashrei” associated with the Tashlumin  but that the other prayers you mention (song of the sea every day, boruch she-amar) seem not to be part of the  Tashlumin arrangement.

Of course, it is possible to say the Psalms of Pesukei Dezimro and to read and/or learn the  song of the sea and the Shema at any time but this is not part of the  Tashlumin arrangement.

Comment: Pesukei dezimra is basically an extension of ashrei anyway.  Is there a reason not to attach it to the ashrei of tashlumin, or of mincha for that matter?  The only possible reason I can think of is hefsek between mincha and tashlumin.  I'm not sure if that's an issue.

Comment: I still want to know what basis some Rabbi's (and Rav's) I've talked to that have said when I asked about davening after chatsos "just daven eveything from modeh ani to aleinu!" is there a basis for this, I heard that the first hacharis can be counted as a nedavah prayer, since you cn daven anything all day, does that have any basis? Also someonlse else said that u can say birkas krias shema and boruch sheamar the whole day since they're just blessings of praise, do u know about this?

Comment: @user2016831 What I quoted is what I believe to be the normal halocho. I know no justification for the practices you mention. Nedavah prayer is very difficult to do and not recommended nowdays.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok but it didn't mentioned psukei dzimra, as well as tachanun, uva litzion, can ustill say all those later?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok take a look at http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48573&pgnum=36

Comment: @user2016831 Thank you for the Torah of Rav Heller. As I said, I gave my understanding from the Shulchan Oruch which is the normally accepted halocho. Regarding  psukei dzimra, tachanun and uva litzion, I refer you to item (1) in my answer - the concept of  tashlumin exists only for the shemoneh esrei. It is possible to address HKB"H in prayer all day as Rav Heller says but halocho does not see them as tashlumin.